# Can we integrate Kibana visualizations in our commercial product?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Can we integrate Kibana visualizations in our commercial product? Are there opensource alternatives for Kibana Visualizations? I'm looking for something opensource and which is capable of visualizing Elasticsearch query results data easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the current status of the dashboard created in kibana as an iFrame to your product.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for something opensource and which is capable of visualizing Elasticsearch query results data.